# Possible to move NSmanagedObject to another NSManagedContext?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have two NSManagedContext's, one parent and one child that i use for concurrency. Specified like this:

```
self.managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];

self.backgroundContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType: NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
self.backgroundContext.parentContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

In one of my view controllers I call this method:

```
[Stream followingStreamForUser:self.user fromDictionary:dict inManagedObjectContext: [AppController sharedAppController].backgroundContext];
```

Calling this method causes the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Illegal attempt to establish a relationship '[...]' between objects in different contexts
```

It seems like `self.user` isn't in my `backgroundContext`. I wonder if it's possible to move my `self.user` object to my `backgroundContext` or if it's possible to see where and when my user object gets added to context X.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try to use an NSManagedObject in the wrong context you will get exceptions while saving.

If you need to access existing objects from a temporary context, then you need to use the object's ID to get a new instance like this:

```
NSManagedObject *user = ...;
NSManagedObject *userInBackgroundContext = [backgroundContext objectWithID:[user objectID]];
```

Then when you save the background context, the changes are persisted to the store, and you just need to get those changes back into your main context.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that can be shared between contexts is the managed object ID. You can obtain it like this:

```
NSManagedObjectID *objectID = self.user.objectID;
```

Then get the equivalent object from the other context like this:

```
User *backgroundUser = [backgroundContext obectWithID:objectID];
```

backgroundUser is now safe to use with other objects from the background context.