# Core Data entity switch contexts

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am currently working with an in memory context in which I have an entity that I would like to move to another context, which is connected to the database. Is there any way to move an entity from a context to another?

I had a look at `mergeChanges(fromRemoteContextSave:into:)`, but I'm not sure if this will do that.

Comment: Take a look at these threads: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998613/how-do-i-copy-or-move-an-nsmanagedobject-from-one-context-to-another https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383606/possible-to-move-nsmanagedobject-to-another-nsmanagedcontext